# iOS 7: Disable message "This cable or accessory is not certified and may not work reliably with this iPhone"?

Tags: iphone, ios, charger

After the upgrade to iOS 7, while using non-Apple certified chargers I receive the warning

> This cable or accessory is not certified and may not work reliably with this iPhone.

AFAIK there is no way to say "Got It", "Suppress Message", etc., and it shows up **every time** I plug in my chargers.

Anyone know of any ways to disable these messages without jailbreaking the iPhone?

Comment: Just be open to an answer that requires jailbreaking. It's quite possible this isn't something we get to disable on iOS 7.x and almost certainly isn't something we can change on iOS 7.0 as delivered. This may be part of a consumer safety initiative that includes a buyback program for non-apple cables and adapters in the US. http://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter-takeback/

Comment: @bmike Absolutely, I personally don't like jail-breaking, but I assume this unfortunately isn't possible. So if someone likes to mention any of those options, by all means go for it :)

Comment: The best and the safest way to disable a safety warning is to use the recommended product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected behavior when you see this message is to simply contact the vendor of the cable or charger and verify that your are in fact safe to charge an iPhone.

I would hate to tell people to disregard a message that could have safety implications. Granted, not all third party cables and/or chargers are faulty, but what if this were a warning that could get you to seek assistance from Apple or the vendor and ensure that a sub-standard part isn't being used to charge your device.

- http://www.apple.com/support/usbadapter-takeback/

Given some of the horribly unsafe chargers that I have personally seen, I don't expect this to be an easy warning to bypass without jailbreaking.

Comment: Thanks for that. I kind of expected this, but wanted to check. I guess I'll have to deal w/ losing 2 seconds of my life everytime I plug in a non apple certified charger =p

Comment: This isn't about safety implications. It's about Apple being evil. Plain and simple. Even when Microsoft had a software certification program, they allowed users to disable the warning. Apple also used to prevent jailbreaking; they would turn your phone into a brick, until the courts ruled it was illegal for them to do so. Customers of iPhones should be furious over this, and as an iPhone customer I am.